# BackboneJS How to include MomentJS <locale> feature

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, momentjs

I want to include the `locale`-feature from `MomentJS` into one of my Backbone Views. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/adding-locale/ - but I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` - and it refers to:

```
return moment.defineLocale('da', {
```

In my config.js I have:

```
require.config({    
   deps: ['main'],

   paths: {

      jquery     : '../lib/jquery-2.1.1.min',
      underscore : '../lib/lodash-2.4.1',
      backbone   : '../lib/backbone',
      moment     : '../lib/moment.min',
      locale     : '../lib/locale/da'
  },
```

And in my View I have:

```
define([
   'app',
   'backbone',
   'moment',
   'locale'
],

function (App, Backbone, moment, locale) {
...
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: have you added moment  to shim section ?

Comment: no, is it necessary? tried it, didnt change anything

Comment: yes, if any lib is not AMD module it is

Comment: tried, didnt solve it... :-/

Comment: looks like need fiddle

Comment: @SHT, did you solve this? I am experiencing a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the oficial documentation http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/

seems to me that there is a little trick to work with requirejs